# Loading Data in dropdown list fastest

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0

I have to load data into some  dropdownlists which includes loading data into datatables through oracle stored procedures.But this make my page loading slow after each postback.  Which technique I should use to make the page loading faster.

To make understanding better, I will quote the instance here

1. We will load the datatable by using oracle connection and stored procedures.
2. We will load this datatable content into dropdownlist
3. On the selection of this one dropdownlist  one more dropdownlist will be populated using the above procedure.

Now my question is how I can make my page load faster by using some tuning techniques or implementing some new ones. My question is specific to asp.net 2.0 framework.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How to do it faster than now depends quite a bit on how you do it now. What is currently the slow part?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code and taking into consideration your concerns regarding the postback load time ("... slow after each postback."), I can suggest that maybe you could leverage the [ASP.NET ViewState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx) functionality to populate your drop-down lists only once during the initial page load and let ASP.NET restore their state (items as well as the selected value) during subsequent postbacks. The pseudocode like the following could do the trick:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (!Page.IsPostBack)
  {
    LoadData();
  }
}

private void LoadData()
{
  // this.List1 refers to the DropDownList control defined in your page markup
  DropDownList list = this.List1; 

  IList<Tuple<string, string>> items = /* Getting items from the database */;
  int selectedItemIndex = /* Getting the selected item index */;

  for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
  {
    list.Items.Add(new ListItem(items[i].Item1, items[i].Item2, i == selectedItemIndex));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

P.S. When you ask this kind of questions, please make sure you post a relevant code snippets because otherwise it's very hard to suggest something since the problem might be not what what it seems to be :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to cache data with which is populated your dropdownlist. There is a lot of techniques, it's all depends on how much data you are loading to your dropdown.

As I expect you have the table with a large amount of columns(like table users - id, name, telephone, birthdate, reletaion1, reletaion2, relation3...) but you need from this table only 2 colums - Id, Name. So:

1) I would recommend you to use SelectListItem as Dto object. 
2) And on application starts load all entire data in your bd as List items to your memory cache, but this will work fine if you have not more than ~10000 objects(depends on your memory amount of server). 
3) Have fun with fast-working cached data.

The other way is to store this object in NoSql like Name-value collection, which is made for storing such kind a data it also will work faster than using the Sql for such a kind of data.